# How temp. exit from Vi editor and return?

Tags: linux, editor, vi

I have waste many time for googling, but didn't find solution. But I have seen this.
Which key combination need use?
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can suspend `vim` if it's in a terminal using `Ctrl-Z` and then say `fg` to get it back to the foreground. You can also run a shell using `! /bin/bash` and then exit it to return to the editor.

Comment: Mind if I ask what you use ! /bin/bash for? I can see it switches back to the shell but any keystroke takes you back to term - is it just to read to the terminal like alt-tab ?

Comment: It doesn't "switch you back to the shell". The `!` command is used to run an external program. In this case, we run the shell `/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 5):

Use control-Z. When you want to get back into vi, use fg from the shell prompt.

Comment: Ha ha, I was going to mention suspend as well, but changed my mind half-way :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you mean a shell by "exit" you can try this command:

```
:shell
```

then you a shell and you can get back to Vi by leaving the shell with

```
exit
```

or by pressing CTRL-D.

Answer (score 2):

What I generally use, when calling vi from a shell, is the `:shell` command to start a new shell, and then Control-D when I’m over (the shell then quits and goes back to the file(s) I was editing with vi).